# For Loop CSV to FBProphet

Tags: pandas, csv, for-loop, model, facebook-prophet

I have what is probably a stupid question.

I have a file which has date, item number, location, and quantity. I want to build a loop that splits out the file by item number and location.

For example I have location - 1, 3, 5, 7, 10
Item Numbers - 1234, 5678, 9873, 2345, etc.

So I want to create a loop that basically breaks out every location and each item number separately. That way I can run fbprophet on each location/item combination.  Is this possible?  If so how?

data = pd.read_csv('FILETIMESERIES.csv', parse_dates=['ORDERDATE'], encoding='ANSI')

Comment: Please update your question with an actual example of your data instead of describing it, as well as the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.groupby(['item number', 'location')])`. This will return a [GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) object. You can use it to loop over the groups (one group per combination of item number and location) or apply directly functions depending on what you exactly want to achieve.

For example to loop over the groups:

```
for group_name, group in data.groupby(['item number', 'location')]):
    # do something on each subdataframe accessed by g"roup"
    my_processing(group)
```

You will find more info on groups in the [groupby user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html)